# Highcharts problem with decimals if there are many data points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I got a problem with a Highcharts Graph. It's a line stock-chart and it works quite well if there are just a few hundred data points but if I try to display a few thousand it shows (in the tooltip) more than 2 up to 13 decimals (eg 16.5772857142857). I'm rounding the data at the beginning to 2 decimals and "valueDecimals" is at 2 in the tooltip. I guess if there are too many data points which are very close, Highcharts tries to find an average. Does someone knows how to limit the decimals generally or had the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is caused by `dataGrouping` feature. You can read more about it in the docs. To turn it off, set:

```
series: [{
    dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false
    },
    data: [...]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3x06skoc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping.enabled

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping